# Bridge for logging systems

Tags: java, logging

I'am developing simple Java event library and I want to support more than one logging system.
I have an idea with using own class named LoggerBridge.

```
public void setLogger(LoggerBridge bridge){

}

public class LoggerBridge{

    public void log(Level, String){}

    ...

}
```

But this solution is not practical at all, is there some other option how to achieve this result ? 
Some bridge, which it supports all types of logging system ?

Comment: They already made those, use for example `SLF4J`. Don't write your own.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? For me the idea of using `Level`s sounds good, that's actually also what other logger libraries do (for example `Log4j`). You need to be more precise on what you want to achieve and why your current solution doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: "supports all types of logging system" is quite demanding.

Comment: @mko he's not trying to reinvent a logger, he's trying to reinvent a logging facade. Also, don't use (or suggest others to use) `java.util.logging` if you value decent logging.

Comment: @mko I am not trying to reinvent logger, I just want to make a class which can be used for many different logging systems.

Comment: *"I want to support more than one logging system"* So you need a [**facade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), i.e. an adapter, e.g. as already implemented by [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/), as [already mentioned by Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720044/java-bridge-for-logging-systems#comment82400556_47720044).

Comment: @Kayaman Your comment should be an answer.  There is no reason to reinvent a logging facade.

Answer (score 0):

This is an age old problem and several logging facades were made to allow you to log things in for example libraries, without forcing the user to use the same logging framework you chose (or try to make multiple logging frameworks work nicely together).

One of the earliest ones was [commons-logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) which is considered outdated these days, but there are a lot of older libraries that use it. It can be bridged to your actual logging system (see below).

Newer ones include [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/). These should be used when you're writing a library, so you'd be programming to the SLF4J API instead of an actual logging implementation.

A [logging bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) is when you have a library that uses for example `log4J`, but your other code is using let's say `SLF4J` with [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) (a quite common combination). The bridge "fakes" being the `log4J` library, when it actually just redirects the logging to your `SLF4J+Logback` combination.